# Java Calendar date error

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

Can anyone please help me understand why I am getting different month values for

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");    
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) 
                   + "--" 
                   + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Surprisingly displays

```
09/09/2012--8
```

Comment: Can we all get a badge for answer pileup? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, [`MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) start from index `0`. So, `January` is 0, `February` is 1, and hence `September` is 8.

**P.S.**: - That's true that this is an `Inconsistency` in `Calendar` class, so I would suggest you to take a look at [**`Joda-Time API`**](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to make your life easier while working with date-time data.

Comment: cal was instantiated using  `cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2010);  `
                        `cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);  `
                        `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`

Comment: @Lai. Then you need to post complete code. We don't see any code there setting the calendar values. If you set `Calendar.MONTH` to 1, then thats `February`.

Comment: Gosh! that solved it. Why the inconsistency, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 returns the first day of the month!

Comment: @Lai. Because thats in the implementaion. See the documentatino of Calendar class. I have given the link in my answer.

Comment: @Lai. You can better use [`Joda Time API`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to make your life easier with Dates.

Answer (score 3):

Your likely problem is that [Calendar uses a zero-based index for months](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH). So the format correctly outputs `9` for September, but the getter returns `8`.

Is this stupid and inconsistent of Calendar? Yes! Use the [Joda-Time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for working with dates and times instead. As far as I'm aware, it's currently the de-facto standard until [JSR 310](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/18/jsr-310-new-java-date-time-api.html) comes around.

Answer (score 2):

Calendar.MONTH return 0-based values i.e. [JANUARY](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.0JANUARY) is represented with 0. That way SEPTEMBER is 8.

Answer (score 1):

Months in Calendar starts in 0

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct. The java.util.Calendar class uses zero-based counting for month numbers. One of many reasons to avoid using the java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

This kind of work is easier with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library. Thankfully it sensibly uses one-based counting such as January = 1, December = 12.

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

// Though not required here for this one purpose, it's better to specify a time zone than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( cal.getTime(), timeZone );

// Extract month. Note how these two lines call similar sounding methods that are actually quite different.
// One returns a primitive int value. The other returns an object of nested class DateTime.Property.
int monthNumber = dateTime.getMonthOfYear();
String monthName = dateTime.monthOfYear().getAsText( Locale.FRENCH );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "monthNumber: " + monthNumber );
System.out.println( "monthName: " + monthName );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-02-10T02:58:35.386-05:00
monthNumber: 2
monthName: février
```