# ConvertDate in Java

Tags: java, date

In my code I take date user input in format dd/mm/yyyy and show the result as string. E.g., if I enter 2/2/2011 it should be shown '2 Feb 2011'. But my code always shows JAN as month.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class ConvertDate {
public static void main(String[] args) {


Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Enter Date: "); 
String ind = sc.nextLine(); 

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
Date d = null;
try {

d=df.parse(ind);

}
catch(ParseException e) {
System.out.println("Unable to parse " + ind);}


DateFormat df3 = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);


String s3 = df3.format(d);


System.out.println("The entered date is: " + s3);

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966652/java-date-problem-in-parsing?rq=1

Comment: See this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986863/java-calendar-date-error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986863/java-calendar-date-error

Comment: Try the Joda DateTime library.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's something more like that:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

`m` is for minute, `M` for month.

Comment: Nizil it will show date again in input format ..i want to show mnth like jan FEB...SO ON

Answer (score 2):

The correct date format should be follows:

```
final DateFormat inputDf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
final DateFormat outputDf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

It will give output as follows:

```
Input:  01/08/2013
Output: 01 Aug 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

In the format string, `m` is minutes, `M` is the month.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect "February" but see "January" it might be due to the indexing of the calendar.
See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986863/java-calendar-date-error)